# Flexbox items are collapsing in Safari, IE11 & IE10

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm having some issues with nested flexbox in Safari, IE11 & IE10. The panels are supposed to be side-by-side (50% width), and have varying amounts of content in them. The `<cite>` element should be anchored to the bottom of the panel and each panel should be the same height.

Here's a codepen to illustrate: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BKNRBY

This works fine in Chrome / Firefox, but in Safari, IE10 and IE11, the panels don't stretch vertically to contain their content.

Can anyone offer any advice?

Comment: As a first step, consider browser compatibility. Safari < 9 and IE10 require vendor prefixes. IE11 has issues that need to be addressed, as well. http://stackoverflow.com/a/35137869/3597276

Comment: The pen is using autoprefixer to handle vendor prefixes.

Comment: Good to know. It wasn't apparent in the code itself. The link I posted above also contains references to common browser bugs and workarounds.

Answer (score 6):

Found it, switching the rule from `flex-basis: 100%` to `flex-basis: auto` on the `blockquote` did the trick.